# How to create a dynamic form with python using translated text as input?

Tags: python, forms, translation

I have an original text that I want to translate. I normally do it manually but I know I could save a lot of time translating automatically the most frequent words and expressions.
I will find out how to translate simple words, the problem is not here. I have read some books on python and I think using string manipulations can be done. 
But I am lost about how to create the output file.

The output file will contain:

- short empty forms ready to be filled wherever there is text that has not been translated
- the translated words wherever they were in the original file
- In the output file I will fill manually the empty forms, after pressing Tab the cursor should jump to the next exmpty form

I am lost here, I know how to do forms on html but the language I am used to is Python.

I would like to know what modules from Python I could use. I need some guidance on this.

Can you recommend me a book or a tool that explains how to do something similar to this?

This is what I want to do, assuming I have managed to create a simple database to translate colors from Spanish to English.

1. The first step contains the original file.
2. The second step contains the automatic translation.
3. In the third step I complete the manual translation.

After finishing everything is grouped into a normal txt file ready to be used.

[image]

I think it is quite clear. I don't expect people to tell me the code to do this,  I just need to know what tools could be used to achieve my goal.

Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 1):

To create an interface that works with a web browser, [Flask for Python](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a good method for creating webforms. There are [tutorials](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) available.

One method for storing data would be an [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) file. That may be more than you need, so I'd recommend starting with a [CSV file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Libraries exist in Python for both CSVs and SQLite.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at those resources. What about doing this in Jupyter? Is there anything in Python to set small empty boxes ready to be filled in?

Comment: Jupyter with a Python kernel can read and write CSV files or SQLite files. If you're looking to read input in Python, try [raw_input](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-in-python/)